# Xcode Localization returning Key instead of value

Tags: xcode, localization

I am adding localization support in my project where I have added Localizable.strings file, and adding key value pair as below:

```
"not_found" = "device not found";
```

I am then adding a label to my viewcontroller file as below:

self.notificationTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"not_found", nil)];

When I run the app label shows not_found instead of "device not found". I have followed tutorials and still not able to figure out why the key is printed. What I could be doing wrong?

Here's what my Project navigator shows:

[image]

each contains single line as shown above. French version has translated string.

Also the storyboard also has localizations enabled and has .strings files:

[image]

Update: 
There is a similar question with not very helpful answers. 
[Localization issue Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9322701/localization-issue-xcode?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

This happens if the localization isn't found.

One problem is that if the compiler finds any problem in a localizable.strings file, that entry and all following entries are silently ignored. So look what's in the file, and see if other entries earlier in the file work.

BTW. [NSString stringWithFormat... ] expects a format string. What you are doing will get you into all kinds of trouble if you ever use a translation that contains a percent character. Just write

```
self.notificationTextLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"not_found", nil);
```

Comment: Thanks. I have enabled base and english localizations and both .strings files have only one line as shown in question. https://www.dropbox.com/s/zx4jdz6t0varzps/Screenshot%202015-09-09%2015.33.52.png?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution! It was something unexpected. I had created a localizable.strings file earlier and It was conflicting with the newly created file. I deleted all new files and kept only Original file. Works like a charm now!